# Getting strange data after webscraping with requests module in Python3

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am currently trying to webscrape Youtube for simple data like getting first ten video titles on the site but unfortunately I get strange data in double square brackets instead of real data.

To webscrape I use requests module in Python3.

This is example of what I get after scraping:

```
 <span id="video-title" title$="[[getSimpleString(data.title)]]" aria-label$="[[data.title.accessibility.accessibilityData.label]]" class="style-scope ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer">[[getSimpleString(data.title)]] </span>
```

This is my code I use

```
import requests
base = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=itil'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0',
        }

    r = requests.get(base, headers=headers)
```

Does anyone know what should I do to get real data instead of those things in [[]] ?

Comment: What "real data" are you expecting? Show the expected result.

Comment: Sorry. I would like to get normal strings instead of those brackets [[]].
Something like this:

`<a id="video-title" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer" title="ITIL - What is it? (Introduction &amp; Best Practices)" href="/watch?v=Swj7WxvKVOU" aria-label="ITIL - What is it? (Introduction &amp; Best Practices) </yt-formatted-string> </a>`


So basically I want this: `title="ITIL - What is it? (Introduction &amp; Best Practices)" ` instead of this:  `title$="[[getSimpleString(data.title)]]"`